# Cross compiling C++ project, Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 3)

Tags: c++, makefile, cross-compiling

I've been working on a c++ project for a while now, but would like to port it over to my arm processor.  I already have all of my cross-compile tools (I'm using CodeSourcery) and thought I could just change my makefile to point to that compiler.  It compiles fine using the default g++, but When try a make pointing to the cross-compiler I get relocation errors:

> /home/oryan/CodeSourcery/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: ServerSocket.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 3)
>   ServerSocket.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [simple_server] Error 1

It seems like I don't have a proper link set up or it's pointing to a wrong location.  I'm not that familiar with makefiles and am probably missing something obvious.  The makefile I've been using is from http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue74/tougher.html with the client side removed:

```
# Makefile for the socket programming example
#

simple_server_objects = ServerSocket.o Socket.o simple_server_main.o

all : simple_server

simple_server: $(simple_server_objects)
         /home/matt/CodeSourcery/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o simple_server $(simple_server_objects)


Socket: Socket.cpp
ServerSocket: ServerSocket.cpp
simple_server_main: simple_server_main.cpp

clean:
        rm -f *.o simple_server
```

Right now I am manually compiling each file and it works great, but I'd like to further my understanding here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you've set your makefile up to link with the new g++ but you haven't changed the compiler you're using to build the objects in the first place.

The easiest way to fix this is to set environment `CXX` to the next compiler, i.e.

```
export CXX=/home/matt/CodeSourcery/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

or just set it for a given `make` by adding `CXX=...` to the command line.

You'll need to `make clean` first but you'll then use the correct compiler for both the compile and link.

You could also specify a new how-to-compile-C++ files rule in your makefile to specify the new compiler but the environment variable is easier:

```
.cc.o:
        /home/.../g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c
```

Comment: I added the CXX variable and it pointed to the cross-compiler great, but now I'm getting    /user/bin/ld: ServerSocket.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40).  So I think there is still an error where it is not pointing to my cross compile tools and instead looking at the default ld.

Comment: Hmm. I remember it's `g++ -print-prog-name=ld` to show you which one it's using but I can't remember how to specify one. I think it'd pick one up from the same directory as cc1plus - do you have an ld in that dir (probably CodeSourcery/libexec/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.2/)? Have you definitely got the binutils installed for your cross compiler?

Comment: g++ -print-prog-name gives me just "ld".  No ld file with cc1plus either.  In CodeSourcery/bin/ there is a arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld though.  Maybe a softlink to arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld?

Comment: softlinking to it did work, but I don't think its a good solution.  Now cross compiling goes off without a hitch, but to compile in regular old g++ I need to kill the softlinks.  So to save one headache I caused another...

Comment: Sorry I haven't forgotten about this - I'd like to know the correct way to pick the ld you want myself but I don't know the answer. I'll see if I can figure it out in the next few days.

Comment: No worries Rup, I'm also still trying.  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of these three rules:

```
Socket: Socket.cpp
ServerSocket: ServerSocket.cpp
simple_server_main: simple_server_main.cpp
```

First of all, the left-hand side of the rule should be the object file I guess, so should have the `.o` suffix.

The second problem, and most likely the root of your problem, is that there is no command to compile the source files, which means that `make` will use the default compiler and not your cross-compiler.