# Problem with link library SQLAPI ++ in Code: Blocks on Raspberry PI 3b +

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, sqlapi++

I have a problem, my goal is to connect to a database, for example MSSQL using C++ on Raspberry Pi and I have a problem with linking the SQLAPI++ library in Code::Blocks, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Please give me a tip or direction...

1.Dowland fies
[downloaded files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG5lw.png)

2.I link the include catalog with the project
[link include to project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc0qH.png)

3.I link the lib catalog with the project
[link lib to project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHkOB.png)

4.I link files the debug
[link files to debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBxQ8.png)

5.I link files the release
[link files to release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6NE1.png)

6.This is my error:
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQg8b.png)

This is my test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SQLAPI.h>

int main()
{
     SAConnection con;
     con.setOption("UseAPI") = "DB-Lib";

try
{
   con.Connect("BEDLAM-M\\SQLEXP2008EN@pubs", "", "", SA_SQLServer_Client);
   SACommand cmd(&con, "select user");
   cmd.Execute();
   if( cmd.FetchNext() )
        printf("USER: %s", cmd[1].asString().GetMultiByteChars());
}
catch(SAException& x)
{
    printf("ERROR %d: %s\n",
        x.ErrNativeCode(), x.ErrText().GetMultiByteChars());

}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Building for 32-bit?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168950/cross-compiling-c-project-relocations-in-generic-elf-em-3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you downloaded x86 (Intel/AMD) Linux based libraries rather than ARM (Raspberry Pi).
I don't think there is an ARM version available.

I would investigate something like this: http://www.freetds.org/index.html